# How do I connect to a Virtual Desktop (Windows Server 2012 R2) with a Linux Client?

Tags: linux, rds, vdi

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 installation with Remote Desktop Services and a Virtualization Host server. I also published 10 virtual desktops.

Now I want to connect to one of the virtual desktops with a linux client.
I tried using rdesktop, freerdp, remmina and x2go but none of those support remote desktop services.

The client always connects to the RDS server and does not get redirected to the virtual desktops.

What do I have to do to get redirected to one of the virtual desktops and not connect to the RDS server?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using FreeRDP you can use the command line interface (https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/CommandLineInterface) to launch a session to your server.
If you add `/load-balance-info:tsv://{resource name}` then you will connect to the virtual desktop.

You can find the appropriate value for `{resource name}` when you download the RDP file for the resource you want to connect to from your RD Web interface.